# AngularJS - Change the ID to match with the hard coded values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some hard-coded values shown in the code, and my method of calling the remaining value has it set to 0 onwards.

How do I set hard-coded `ValueList` remain at 1 - 3, in this case, but the values called by the GET is at 4.

```
  $scope.valueList = [{
        'id': 1, 'name': 'Example 1'
    }, {
        'id': 2, 'name': 'Example 2'
    }, {
        'id': 3, 'name': 'Example 3'
    }];
    SpringDataRestService.get(
        {"collection": "users"},
        function (response) {                   
            var user= response._embedded.users;
            for (var i = 0, len = user.length; i < len; i++) {
                var newUser = {id: user[i].id, name: userGroupType[i].name};
                $scope.valueList .push(newUser );
            }
        },
        function (response) {                   // Failure Function
            $scope.alerts.push(new DentAlert(AlertType.ERROR, generateAlertMessage(response)));
        }
    );
```

Comment: Do you want to maintain the array index and id's to be equal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep new array values at the bottom then use **push** method of array object and if you want to keep newly inserted array values at top use **unshift** method of array for e.g

```
var array= ["foo", "bar"];
array.unshift("baz");
console.log(array);
```

**Result** : ["baz","foo", "bar"]

```
var array= ["foo", "bar"];
array.push("baz");
console.log(array);
```

**Result** : ["foo", "bar","baz"]

Comment: He asks about assigning an id to user based on hard coded valueList and push it after the hard coded array.

Answer (score 0):

Very basic exmaple here.

You need to loop through users, and set user.id to valueList length, then push user to ValueList.

```
const valueList = [{id: 0}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}];

function addValuesToExistingArray(hardCodedValues, newValues) {
    newValues.forEach(function(value, index) {
        value.id = hardCodedValues.length;
        hardCodedValues.push(value);
    });
    return hardCodedValues;
}

const result = addValuesToExistingArray(valueList, [{id: 0}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}])
```

Things to keep in mind. I recommend you to start hard coded `valueList` from id: 0.

Arrays **DO NOT** start at 1.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood the question correctly but if you want your newUser to start with 4, then you should try this

```
 var newUser = {id: user[i].id + valueList.length+1, name: userGroupType[i].name};
```

But i would recommend to start with id value as 0 in hardcoded and use newUser like below:

```
var newUser = {id: user[i].id + valueList.length, name: userGroupType[i].name};
```